# I have to load users from a table into Certification Definition. Which api and method is to be used for it

Tags: oim

I have a query that fetches users which are to be loaded into Certitification Definition.I am not sure which method i must use for setting these users into definition

Comment: Can't you specify a criteria in your certification definition which will produce the same list of users?

Comment: Hi, Can you elaborate more on this please?

Comment: check the [OIM Admin guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40329_01/admin.1112/e27149/managecert.htm#BABFDFHC) chapter 6.3.1.1 step 6, where they describe how you can specify a criteria for selecting users to be certified